# Passed ref to child is null

Tags: reactjs

I have MUI Drawer component in which I render another component called `NotificationsMenu`. The `NotificationsMenu` is a MUI Popover component.

I want to anchor the Popover to the Drawer component so the Popover will be positioned relative to the Drawer which can be open (240px width) or closed (66px width).

I think I should use a `ref` for this. If I have the reference to the Drawer (parent component) I can just use that to set the Anchor for the Popover:

```
// NotificationsMenu.tsx

const NotificationsMenu = (props, ref) => {
  console.log(props, ref);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(ref.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListItem disablePadding>
      ...
      </ListItem>

      <Popover
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        ...
       > Content
      <Popover/>
    </>
}
```

```
// DrawerContainer.tsx

import React, {useRef} from 'react';

export const DrawerContainer = () => {
  const elRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
      <List>
        <NotificationsMenu ref={elRef}/>
      </List>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

This isn't working because `ref.current` in the `Notifications.menu` is `null`.
Using `react": "^17.0.2",`

Comment: By default, you may not use the ref attribute on function components because they don’t have instances. Class component will work with ref. From docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to destructuring the ref on notificationmenu components like this:

```
const NotificationsMenu = ({ ref }) => {
  console.log(ref);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(ref.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListItem disablePadding>
      ...
      </ListItem>

      <Popover
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        ...
       > Content
      <Popover/>
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. Just to clarify, the child component `NotificationsMenu` had an `forwardRef` assigned:

```
export default forwardRef(NotificationsMenu);
```

This allows the usage of ref in functional components.

The issue was that I needed to pass the Ref also on the `Drawer` component:

```
<Drawer variant="permanent" open={open} ref={elRef}>
```